# Generating Random Strings of Characters including Special Characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that generates random strings of characters (passwords) that contain exactly 8 characters. My issue is that it populates only numbers and characters.

1) I would like to include special characters to the mix and to make sure at least one special character is always included in each string.

2) I need to add a condition that each string always contains at least one upper case character, at least one lower case, at least one number.

This is the code I have but I can't figure out how to include these conditions to make it work as I need. I've tried a lot of googling to make it work specifically for this code but can't figure it out. Can you please advise?

```
Sub MakeRandom()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim L As Double
    Dim iTemp As Integer
    Dim sNumber As String
    Dim bOK As Boolean

    Range("G5:G148").Activate
    Randomize
    L = InputBox("Amount of Passwords:")
      For J = 1 To L
        sNumber = ""
        For K = 1 To 8
            Do
                iTemp = Int((122 - 48 + 1) * Rnd + 48)
                Select Case iTemp
                    Case 48 To 57, 97 To 122
                        bOK = True
                    Case Else
                        bOK = False
                End Select
            Loop Until bOK
            bOK = False
            sNumber = sNumber & Chr(iTemp)
        Next K
        ActiveCell.Value = sNumber
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next J
End Sub
```

I'd appreciate any useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not introduce Long string, containing all legal characters and then having your algo pick chars from random positions of this string? That way you have easy control of what can be in your Passwords.

To ensure the conditions are true, I would place the Password Generation in an infinite Loop, that only end when all conditions are satisfied. As Long as this this is actually possible (that is, your conditions can all be true at the same time), this Loop will eventually end (due to law of large numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I have something that might help you. I use a different method but the result should be similar. I've adapted it to your constraints, but may have missed something.

Mine works like this: I have a sheet called `ChrSrc` with all characters that I want to be able to include in the string. The characters have been divided into four columns. From column A to D it's lower case letters, upper case letters, numbers, special characters.

An array is made to store the characters and create the random string. The array contains 3 'columns'. the first gives a number between 1 and 4 to determine from which column it should get it's character. The first four are always 1,2,3,4 to makes sure every type of character is used at least once. The other 4 (or more if the random string is longer) are randomly filled.

The second 'column' is then filled with the actual character to add to the random string. And lastly the third 'column' is filled with zeros. These will be used to track which characters have been used in the random string.

Once the array has been filled, the `do while loop` is used to select the order of the characters randomly. After a character has been added, the zero in the array is changed to a one, to make sure every character gets used once.

By the end your random string is in the variable `RandomString` and you can write it to a cell or do whatever with it.

If you want to create multiple strings in one go, I would suggest writing a small caller sub, that calls this one x amount of times. Or add a loop and inputbox into this one.

Hope that helps.

```
Sub CreateString()
    Dim StringArray() As Variant
    Dim PositionCount As Long
    Dim Lr As Long
    Dim RandomString As String
    Dim arrIndex As Long
    Dim Loopcount As Long
    Dim StringLength As Long

    StringLength = 8

    ReDim StringArray(1 To StringLength, 1 To 3)

    For PositionCount = 1 To StringLength

        If PositionCount > 4 Then

            StringArray(PositionCount, 1) = Random(4)

        Else

            StringArray(PositionCount, 1) = PositionCount

        End If
        'lastrow for each character category, adjust as needed
        Select Case StringArray(PositionCount, 1)
            Case Is <= 2
                Lr = 26
            Case Is = 3
                Lr = 10
            Case Is = 4
                Lr = 17
        End Select

        StringArray(PositionCount, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ChrSrc").Cells(Random(Lr), StringArray(PositionCount, 1))
        StringArray(PositionCount, 3) = 0

    Next

    Do While Len(RandomString) < StringLength

        arrIndex = Random(StringLength)

        If StringArray(arrIndex, 3) = 0 Then

            RandomString = RandomString & StringArray(arrIndex, 2)
            StringArray(arrIndex, 3) = 1

        End If
        Loopcount = Loopcount + 1

    Loop


 End Sub

 Function Random(Max As Long)

    Random = Int(Max * Rnd) + 1

 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

- Where possible, it's advisable to avoid using `Activate` and `Select`. In your case, you could create an array of random strings and then write the array to the sheet. The length of the array could be controlled by the value returned by `InputBox`.
- Your code may benefit from: `L = InputBox("Amount of Passwords:", Type:=1)` which, if I'm reading the documentation correctly, validates that the input is numeric.
- My understanding is that you should use type `Long` instead of `Integer` under normal circumstances (as `Integer`s are now converted to `Long`s under the hood). Moreover, in this context where you're receiving arbitrary user input, `Integer` type overflows at 32768. If you enter 32768 (for example) or any larger number into the `InputBox` you should see an unhandled overflow error.

With reference to the approach described in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903244/8811778):

```
Option Explicit

Private Function CreateRandomString(Optional ByVal lengthOfOutput As Long = 8, Optional ByVal minimumCountOfNumbers As Long = 1, Optional ByVal minimumCountOfLetters As Long = 1, Optional ByVal minimumCountOfSymbols As Long = 1) As String

    Dim countRemaining As Long
    countRemaining = lengthOfOutput - (minimumCountOfLetters + minimumCountOfNumbers + minimumCountOfSymbols)

    Debug.Assert countRemaining >= 0

    Const LETTERS_ALLOWED As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Const NUMBERS_ALLOWED As String = "0123456789"
    Const SYMBOLS_ALLOWED As String = "!""£$%^&*()-_+[]{};:'@#" ' Change as necessary, I do not know what symbols you want included.

    Dim toJoin() As String
    ReDim toJoin(1 To 4)

    toJoin(1) = GetRandomCharactersFromText(LETTERS_ALLOWED, minimumCountOfLetters, duplicatesAllowed:=False)
    toJoin(2) = GetRandomCharactersFromText(NUMBERS_ALLOWED, minimumCountOfNumbers, duplicatesAllowed:=False)
    toJoin(3) = GetRandomCharactersFromText(SYMBOLS_ALLOWED, minimumCountOfSymbols, duplicatesAllowed:=False)

    ' I arbitrarily pad the rest of the string with random letters, but you can change this logic.
    toJoin(4) = GetRandomCharactersFromText(LETTERS_ALLOWED, countRemaining, duplicatesAllowed:=False)

    Dim outputString As String
    outputString = Join(toJoin, vbNullString)

    ' This step is meant to scramble the characters in the string.
    ' Otherwise, the returned string's structure would reflect the code above:
    '   • w letters, followed by x numbers, followed by y symbols, followed by z characters
    ' which stops it being pseudo-random.
    outputString = GetRandomCharactersFromText(outputString, Len(outputString), False)
    CreateRandomString = outputString
End Function

Private Function RandomBetween(ByVal lowerLimit As Long, ByVal upperLimit As Long) As Long
    ' Could use Application.RandBetween instead (maybe). But maybe there is some performance difference.
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function
    RandomBetween = Int((upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1) * Rnd + lowerLimit)
End Function

Private Function GetRandomCharactersFromText(ByVal someText As String, ByVal numberOfCharactersToGet As Long, Optional ByVal duplicatesAllowed As Boolean = True) As String
    ' Returns n characters from a given string. Characters are chosen pseudo-randomly.
    ' "duplicatesAllowed" controls whether a given index can be chosen more than once.

    Dim chosenIndexes() As Long
    ReDim chosenIndexes(1 To numberOfCharactersToGet)

    Dim characterIndex As Long
    For characterIndex = 1 To numberOfCharactersToGet
        Do While True
            Dim randomCharacterIndex As Long
            randomCharacterIndex = RandomBetween(1, Len(someText))

            If duplicatesAllowed Then Exit Do
            If IsError(Application.Match(randomCharacterIndex, chosenIndexes, 0)) Then Exit Do
        Loop
        chosenIndexes(characterIndex) = randomCharacterIndex
    Next characterIndex

    Dim chosenCharacters() As String
    ReDim chosenCharacters(1 To numberOfCharactersToGet)

    For characterIndex = 1 To numberOfCharactersToGet
        randomCharacterIndex = chosenIndexes(characterIndex)
        chosenCharacters(characterIndex) = Mid(someText, randomCharacterIndex, 1)
    Next characterIndex

    GetRandomCharactersFromText = Join(chosenCharacters, vbNullString)
End Function
```

- This is just my interpretation of the approach posted by the user. That user may have implemented their approach differently.
- Majority of the work is done by the `GetRandomCharactersFromText` function.
- You can probably get rid of the nested `For K = 1 to 8` loop and replace with something like `ActiveCell.Value = CreateRandomString(lengthOfOutput:=8, minimumCountOfNumbers:=1, minimumCountOfSymbols:=1)` (although you should avoid using `ActiveCell` and, in general, relying on objects to be active).
- Lastly, based on certain parts of your code, it seems this code is meant to generate passwords. I'm no security expert so I will refrain from providing security-related suggestions/advice. You may or may not benefit from reading https://xkcd.com/936/ and the related discussion https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6096/71460.